# Can't launch file.app but can launch file.app/Contents/MacOS/file

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have an app on python+PyQt5, and I'm building it with Pyinstaller for MacOS by command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed main.py
```

It creates an "main.app" file in "district" directory, but when I'm trying to launch .app file (both from terminal and by mouseclicking) app crashes with error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application .../dist/main.app with error -10810.
```

When I'm launching main.app/Contents/MacOS/main -- everything is ok.
I have to mention, that my app uses some datafiles, which I put in dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/ and /dist directories (just for test)

Comment: When mouse clicking the app do you get a crash report which you can paste?

Comment: No, app just silently crashes in ~1 second

Comment: Have you tried using a launcher script? If you can launch by calling `main` from the terminal, a script should also be able to call it. The script also goes in Contents/MacOS and you name it `main`, renaming the real `main` to `somethingelse`, and calling `somethingelse` in the script. The new script must have the executable bit set, so `chmod +x` it.

Comment: @RichardBarber, what do you mean "launcher script"? I tried to launch main.app from terminal (with error I mentioned). Do you mean it have sense to launch it by additional script? 
If I rename main.app/Contents/MacOS/main to something else -- I got the same error when launching .app from terminal, but this time when I'm launching it by mouse click I have error "main can't be opened"

Comment: When you double click the app, the loader script is called by launchservices who reads the name of the executable in Info.plists.  Here is an example launcher i wrote for filmulator https://github.com/CarVac/filmulator-gui/blob/highlightrecovery/filmulator-gui/resources/macos/filmulator-gui

Comment: You can see there are optional exported variables which affect the environment that exec's your ultimate target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created launcher script in MacOS dir, changed executable file to launcher script in Info.plists, and called main from launcher script. But everything remains same. Really strange thing for me -- I got same error when renamed executable file in Info.plists to some random non-existent file. So, this error means that some file can't be found?